# Close only code folds using evil

Tags: spacemacs, evil, code-folding

How do I close all code folds (but not comments) with `evil`'s code folding?

For now I'm using `evil-close-folds` and `evil-open-folds`, but it closes all folds, including comments.

I'm using `spacemacs 0.300.0@26.3` with the `emacs` edit style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(setq hs-hide-comments-when-hiding-all nil)
```

evil relies on `hs-minor-mode` for folding comments.  and `hs-minor-mode` provides
`hs-hide-comments-when-hiding-all` option to control whether hide comments.